# pagination with sorting in grails

Tags: sorting, grails, pagination

I need to display the list based on sorting on "Participant_Name" field. I am using the below code to fetch the data from domain class and sending it to my gsp -

```
def eventName = "${params.EventNameList}"

if(!params.max)
{
    params.max = 5
}

def ParticipantRec = EventList.findAllByEvent_Name(
    eventName, params).sort { it.Participant_Name }
```

There is no error as such but the records are not coming in sorted order. Rather, the list is getting sorted for record range.For example, If the list is -

```
["SUNNY","RAHUL",ANIL","BABY","AKSHAY","CAD","JOSEPH")
```

then the output is coming as -

```
"ANIL","BABY","CAD","RAHUL","SUNNY"
```

and then

```
"AKSHAY","JOSEPH"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call sort on the result of the finder call with max passed into it, what you get is the first `max` entries sorted. Instead pass the pagination and sorting information the same way that you're already passing `max`. See the examples for [findAllBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) in the Grails online documentation:

```
def results = Book.findAllByTitle("The Shining",
              [max: 10, sort: "title", order: "desc", offset: 100])
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tweaked dynamic finder methods mentioned by Nathan useful for circumstantial events, you can also tell your domain class to automatically sort by a specified property in the mapping closure.

For example if you always wanted EventList.list() to return a list of all EventList objects sorted by Participant_Name, you could set up your mapping closure as follows:

```
class EventList {

    String Participant_Name

    static mapping = {
        sort "Participant_Name"
    }
}
```

This will make it so anytime EventList objects are queried, they will be returned sorted by Participant_Name unless otherwise specified. Note that by default they will be sorted in ascending order, which in this example would be alphabetical order. If you wanted to customize this behavior you would need to declare it as follows

```
static mapping = {
    sort Participant_Name: "desc" // or 'asc' for ascending, which is the default
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.When i work with the above approach, then i am getting the error as below -

Comment: Could not resolve property - Participant_Name of class EventList even though the property exists